# Ionic build Android failed parse error

Tags: java, android, cordova, build, ionic-framework

I have a problem with Ionic build Android: When I try 
to build my app with Android platform, I get a error

```
***Config:***
NodeJS 4.4.5
Ionic 1.7.15
JDK 1.8.0_65   
target=android-23
```

when I run command:

```
>ionic build android
```

I have this error:

```
D:\ionic\MyInstitutBat>ionic build android
Running command: D:\Tools\nodejs\node.exe D:\ionic\MyInstitutBat\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js D:\ionic\MyInstitutBat
add to body class: platform-android
ANDROID_HOME=D:\Tools\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources
:generateDebugSources
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
PARSE ERROR:
unsupported class file version 52.0
...while parsing com/ionicframework/starter/BuildConfig.class

PARSE ERROR:
unsupported class file version 52.0
...while parsing com/ionicframework/starter/MainActivity.class

PARSE ERROR:
unsupported class file version 52.0
...while parsing com/ionicframework/starter/R.class

PARSE ERROR:
unsupported class file version 52.0
...while parsing com/ionicframework/starter/R$attr.class

PARSE ERROR:
unsupported class file version 52.0
...while parsing com/ionicframework/starter/R$drawable.class

PARSE ERROR:
unsupported class file version 52.0
...while parsing com/ionicframework/starter/R$string.class

PARSE ERROR:
unsupported class file version 52.0
...while parsing com/ionicframework/starter/R$xml.class
7 errors; aborting

 FAILED


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2 mins 23.749 secs
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit
value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"D:\ionic\MyInstitutBat\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b D:\ionic\MyInstitutBat\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.d
aemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
```

How can I do to solve this problem? Thank you for your help.

Note: try with K `1.7.0_80`, it's not working

Comment: do you tried with remove platform and add again then do for build?

Comment: I removed platform and add again then build again. ==> BUILD SUCCESS. The problem is resolved.

Comment: then what's the result?

Comment: BUILD SUCCESS. Thanks for idea.

Comment: wohoo.. Happy to help you. :) can i make answer of it and you approved as answer ? ;)

Comment: Now I have another problem. My phone and my computer are connected to the same network, and i can access wamp through my computer IP address, my webservice is in wamp www folder so I build my android app client with my computer IP as url to wamp server app: witth my phone when a try to display data from server app, it's does not work.

Comment: can you connect that phone to machine and try to get error in google inspect device console ?

Comment: For your previous comment: Yes you can, I'll approve

Comment: No, I cannot because, My phone usb port not working

Comment: please use blutooth debugging set up that, if you are not aware please google about configuration according to your mobile model and try to fetch debugger console and error while calling service of wamp. and start total new thread of question with that. gentel reminder: I add answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There is not specific error logs what you mentioned that shows any error with your code.

There may be some ionic/cordova configuration miss-match while add platform.

please remove and add platform with one of following code and try for work again.

> 1) **cordova platform rm android**  and **cordova platform add android**
>
> or
>
> 2) **ionic platform rm android**  and **ionic platform add android**

Comment: Build Successful after appplying method 2) i.e > ionic platform remove android  and then > ionic platform android. Thank you. works well :),  my problem is solved.

Comment: Then mark as answered so of other face same issue they can also resolved with given solution. Glad to help you.